# Since installing windows 7 on my laptop Dual screen is not working

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Since installing windows 7 on my laptop i am running in to some problems, that i did not have when my laptop (lenovo ideapad 100) had windows 10.

I always have a second screen connected but when i connect the hdmi cable from my tv to my laptop nothing happens. It dos not even register that there is a second screen connected.

Windows update dos not change anything

Do any of you know whats wrong and how to fix it? (if more info is needed, i will provide that)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you already checked in the Control Panel's Screen Resolution section? This will allow you to run some processes to detect new displays, change their orientation, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, 

I already looked there and it dos not detect a second screen

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in my laptop awhile back. A simple fix was to just reinstall the display and motherboard/laptop drivers from the manufactures website.

Oftentimes when doing a reinstall/clean install of a system old drivers will be deleted and default drivers will be added by the OS. While these work in the majority of cases not all cases will be handled or work at the optimal performance.

Also of note, if you immediately attempt to use the extra port after installing/upgrading your OS not all drivers will have finished installing. So make sure you are updated to the latest version of windows as well as updating your main drivers previously mentioned.

Hope this helps, cheers

EDIT

After further thinking, make sure the cable & monitor you are using work with other systems and machines, this way you rule out faulty hardware.